# When uploading, where do I set the php.ini parameters?

Tags: configuration, parameters, php

In the script where the upload form is, or the script that processes the action?

**Example parameters:**

```
memory_limit
```

**EDIT**: Ok, let me clarify. First, I didn't know the 2nd, 3rd and 4th parameter could not be changed using `ini_set()`. Now, I want to know where exactly I should call the `ini_set()` function. In the form script or the action handling script?

Here's an example to illustrate what I'm looking for:

**form.php**

```
<form action="post.php">
  <input type="text" name="search" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php //handle search ?>
```

So under which file must my `ini_set()` function should go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set these parameters initially from `php.ini`. You cannot change this from a PHP script except `memory_limit`, for the remaining Just search for those keys you mentioned in `php.ini` and change their values.

For `memory_limit` you can use following snippet at your processing page handling the uploads like in your case at ***`post.php`***

```
ini_set("memory_limit","16M");
```

### OR

You can create a .htaccess file at the root directory, if your server support `mod_rewrite` modules you can change them like this

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Comment: Thanks for that information, i was under the impression all php.ini parameters could be changed dynamically in the script. Now where exactly do I place that function? Say I have a script form.php with <form action="post.php"></form>, do I place that function in form.php or post.php?

Comment: I am guessing at the `post.php`(if this is the file, where you upload your file)? BTW, as @manu tried to mention, you can modify apaches's configuaration usign a .htaccess file or custom php.ini placed at the root of the site. But unfortunately those three cannot be changed from the function.

Comment: @Starx: Can you please modify the answer to match the right answer, so anyone coming to look for it will find it easily. Thanks!

Comment: @gAMBOOKa, Check my update... and tell me if its more helpful or needs improvement

Comment: @Starx: Please mention the answer to the original question, that post.php is where the ini_set() functions go, otherwise it's good, quite descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You set them in the php.ini file, on your server. The location of this file depends on your server and its setup. On Linux it can usually be found under the /etc/php*** directory. On Windows, in the PHP installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

- you can use [`ini_set`](http://fr.php.net/ini_set) to set those parameters dynamicly
- you can set them in your virtualhost/Location section of apache
- you can set them in some htaccess using `php_value` directive
- you can set them in your php.ini

So you have a lot of possibilities depending the one you are using the parameters might be enabled to the whole server, a script in particular, a website in particular, an url in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in the document root and add the following lines

```
php_value memory_limit 100M
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
```

You can set the size you required.

max_file_uploads cannot be changed.
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50684&edit=1